question about career advice
Would this forum appropriate for questions about career advice? It would be nice to have the advice of many people from this forum in regards of financial career. If not, please, suggest some possible alternatives to this forum.

No, absolutely not. This is not the place for general career advice. No no no. We get so many "how do I become a quant" questions that many of the top users are inclined to close a career question without even reading it.
If you're interested in breaking into the industry, try QuantNet. And if you're still in school, talk to your adviser or career center.

any specific meta post discussing this? The only question I can find is Are questions about "being a quant" in scope?, which says yes
